# Remove whitespace in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, string

How can one remove whitespace from a string in as3?

I would like to be able to remove all carriage returns, spaces, tabs etc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use RegExp.

```
var rex:RegExp = /[\s\r\n]+/gim;
var str:String = "This is            a string.";

str = str.replace(rex,'');
// str is now "Thisisastring."
```

For trimming front and back of strings, use

```
var rex:RegExp /^\s*|\s*$/gim;
```

Comment: How can I create my own RegExp. Is there any tuts available?

Comment: The asterisk is wrong here, since asterisk will also match zero length strings and if you'd want to replace all the whitespaces with one space it would not work as expected. Use the plus sign instead - var rex:RegExp = /[\s\r\n]+/gim;

Comment: @Ofir: The OP asked only about removal. You're adding a new condition, which is a kind of scope-creep for this question. I answered the question that was there, not all possible questions that could be derived from it.

Comment: @Robusto: Your answer works great but it is a bit of an overkill. A whitespace is not a zero length string, hence replacing zero length strings was not part of the question either. Anyways, replacing the asterisk with a plus sign would better answer the question since it will replace ONLY the whitespaces.

Comment: @Ofir: The answer is not overkill for removing (again, not *replacing*) whitespace. Say you wanted to implement a trim function for strings. You would definitely use the `^\s*` and `\s$` then.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the AS3 Flex libraries, there's `StringUtil.trim(" my string ")` too. [See here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/StringUtil.html#trim%28%29) for the docs.

It doesn't do exactly what the OP was after, but as this was the top answer on google for AS3 String trimming, I thought it'd be worth posting this solution for the more usual Stringy trimmy requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Tested and works on AnimateCC for iOS air app:

```
// Regular expressions
var spaces:RegExp = / /gi; // match "spaces" in a string
var dashes:RegExp = /-/gi; // match "dashes" in a string

// Sample string with spaces and dashes
loginMC.userName.text = loginMC.userName.text.replace(spaces, ""); // find and replace "spaces"
loginMC.userName.text = loginMC.userName.text.replace(dashes, ":"); // find and replace "dashes"

trace(loginMC.userName.text);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of removing not only spaces but any char for that matter, is as follows,

```
//Tested on Flash CS5 and AIR 2.0

//Regular expressions
var spaces:RegExp = / /gi; // match "spaces" in a string
var dashes:RegExp = /-/gi; // match "dashes" in a string

//Sample string with spaces and dashes
var str:String = "Bu  s ~ Tim  e - 2-50-00";
str = str.replace(spaces, ""); // find and replace "spaces"
str = str.replace(dashes, ":"); // find and replace "dashes"

trace(str); // output: Bus~Time:2:50:00
```