# as3 remove white space

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to remove / replace white space from a string in as3. The string comes from xml and than written into text field. to compare the strings I  am trying to remove white spaces

```
                var xmlSentence:String=myXML.SENTENCE[thisSentence];
                var tfSentence=e.target.text;

                var rex:RegExp = /\s+/;

                trace(xmlSentence.replace(rex, "-"));
                trace(tfSentence.replace(rex, "-"));

                That code outputs like this:
                She-has a dog
               -She has a dog
```

I also tried different rex patterns. the problem is that though there are spaces in both string -which are same- it finds only one space but not the same one in both strings.
Could you help me to solve this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: this related post has a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692365/remove-whitespace-in-as3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the g flag to indicate recursive changes

var rex:RegExp = /\s+/g ;

Within your Actionscript code, select the RegExp keyword, then goto the 'Help' menu and choose 'Flash Help' for more info on flags.